# while infinite loop SH does not work as expected on docker startup

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, sh, kibana

I have sh code (DashBoardImport.sh) like down below. It checks apı response to import a kibana dashboard in a infinite loop, If it gets a reponse with success, it breaks the loop :

```html
#!/bin/sh
# use while loop to check if kibana is running 
while true
do
    response=$(curl -X POST elk:5601/api/saved_objects/_import -H "kbn-xsrf: true" --form file=@/etc/elasticsearch/CityCountDashBoard.ndjson | grep -oE "^\{\"success")
    #curl -X GET elk:9200/git-demo-topic | grep -oE "^\{\"git"  > /dev/null
    #match=$?
    echo $response
    if [ '{"success' = $response ]
        then
            echo "Running import dashboard.."
            #curl -X POST elk:5601/api/saved_objects/_import -H "kbn-xsrf: true" --form file=@/etc/elasticsearch/CityCountDashBoard.ndjson
            break
        else
            echo "Kibana is not running yet"
            sleep 5
    fi
done
```

I run DashBoardImport.sh via docker file:

```html
ADD  ./CityCountDashBoard.ndjson /etc/elasticsearch/CityCountDashBoard.ndjson
ADD  ./DashBoardImport.sh /etc/elasticsearch/DashBoardImport.sh
#ENTRYPOINT /etc/elasticsearch/DashBoardImport.sh &  

USER root

RUN chmod +x /etc/elasticsearch/DashBoardImport.sh
#RUN /etc/elasticsearch/DashBoardImport.sh &
RUN nohup bash -c "/etc/elasticsearch/DashBoardImport.sh" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I tried many options as you can see commented out. The sh works perfectly when I run it manually on the Docker Container. I kill the kibana service. then run the code. after I started the kibana, code succesfully workes as expected and imports  the dashboard. But It does not work when it start on container automatically.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks alot in advance :)

Comment: You need to quote `response`, as it appears to be a JSON object that almost certainly has whitespace in it. `[` is likely failing with a syntax error, nothing to do with whether the object has a key named `success`.

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and install `jq` in the Docker image, so you can write something sane like `if curl ... | jq -e '.success' > /dev/null; then ...`.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the response :) yeah, you are right btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `RUN` step executes in a temporary container until the command returns and then docker captures the changes to the filesystem as a new layer in your image. Nothing else remains, no environment variables, running processes, etc, only the filesystem changes.

So when you `RUN nohup ... &` that process immediately returns since it's in the background (`nohup ... &` explicitly does that), and so the container exits, killing any processes that were running in the container, and captures the filesystem changes made, if any, to your image.

If you want something to run when you start the container, add it to your ENTRYPOINT or CMD.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @BMitch this makes sense.  But there is a problem, I can not execute ENTRYPOINT or CMD. on background.

I tried:

ENTRYPOINT /etc/elasticsearch/DashBoardImport.sh
CMD ["&"]

  or  CMD ["/etc/elasticsearch/DashBoardImport.sh","&"]

Comment: It's the same rule for ENTRYPOINT/CMD, once they return the container exits. And `&` is a shell construct. So you need to have a shell script as your entrypoint that remains running but launches your other command in the background. You'll want to consider what to do if your background command fails, or how to get logs, without breaking what you do in the foreground.

Comment: I get it what you mean. I created different conationer to check kibana. I think it is the best way you can do. This was a good information to understand docker. Thak you @BMitch :)